# Keep getting ValueError while training on tf.data.datasets and include validation_data

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-data-validation

Running the `model.fit(...)` method on my dataset. I keep getting errors like this:

```
ValueError: in user code:
... 
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(160, 160, 3), dtype=float32)
        * False
        * False
        * 0.99
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

However, I only get this error when I include `validatin_data` in my `model.fit(...)` call.
Any clarification about this would help. I do not mind sharing my Google Colab notebook to show how I construct my training and validation data with `tf.data.Dataset`.

My code can be found here, on [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l_aaV_pSSrGwslyUXy0BF1VTnKzRZuNs?usp=sharing).

Comment: share your code please

Comment: [Code on Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l_aaV_pSSrGwslyUXy0BF1VTnKzRZuNs?usp=sharing)
@lovishkumar